# Convert a string to function (callable) and keep it cached

Tags: php, eval

I'm trying to make a little benchmarking script where I can enter short pieces of code for quick evaluation of my anticipations. I imagine it similar to jsPerf (but password-protected for security reasons).

The main loop should look like this:

```
  public function run(&$t, $count) {
    //Run setup function
    if(is_callable($this->setup))
      call_user_func($this->setup);
    //Save inital time
    $t($this->name);
    //THE MAIN LOOP
    for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) {
        call_user_func($this->fn);
    }
    //Save end time
    $t($this->name."_end");
    //return time difference
    return $t[$this->name."-".$this->name."_end"];
  }
```

However, this will only work with static approach - with functions defined while making the script:

```
//New instance of tester
$b = new Benchmarker();
$b->add(
  //Name
  "touch",
  //closure
  function() {
    touch("file.txt");
  },
  //Code seen in final reports
  "touch()"
);
```

So as you see, I use `call_user_func`, not `eval`. Besides the fact that it's evil function in it's nature, I want to avoid it for performance reasons. If I'm testing a code that takes about 10ns to process and *eviluation* takes about 100ns, my results will be rather random.

This is why I'm looking for a way to convert string to a callable object. You can think about it like one-time eval.

```
$callable = string_to_callable("function() {echo \"Hello world!\";}");
$b->add(
  //Name
  "echo",
  //callable object
  $callable,
  //Code seen in final reports
  "echo \"...\""
);
```

**Is that possible?**

**<sub>Note:</sub>**

I can see funny workaround using `include`:

```
//Code received from the user
$code = "echo \"Hello world!\";";
//Random name for a new function
$rndname = "fn_".rand(0,100000);  //There are smarter ways to do this of course
//String of the new function
$func = "function $rndname() {{$code}}";
//Define a filename
$f = $rndname.".php";
//Put the code in the file
file_put_contents($f, "<?php\n$func\n?".">");
//Include the new script
include $f;
//Call the function
call_user_func($rndname);
//Delete the file
unlink($f);
```

I really **do hope** that I **won't need** the code above!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from creating a new file, there may be a closure trick:

```
function string_to_callable($string) {
  return eval("return function() {{$string}};");
}
```

Comment: What would be the solution if the `$string` contains several functions?

Comment: @Avatar My code only worked for code snippet, not a full function. This is many years back, but unless something changed in PHP, you will probably need to save the snippet to file and then include the file.

Comment: That's exactly what I did. Saving the $strings to one PHP file and including this into my code afterwards.